# prove/disprove: If the language $L$ is such that for every $CFL$ $L'$ , the language $L \cap L'$ is $CFL$, then $L$ is regular?

Tags: computability, regular-language, context-free-grammar

Hey guys I got this question in my homework and I can't figure out what to do:

If the language $L$ is such that for every $CFL$  $L'$ , the language $L \cap L'$ is $CFL$, then $L$ is regular?

I sat down next to it few hours with no clue..

They gave us a huge hint it is not true. I think $L =\{a^nb^n\}$ when $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$ is a counterexample but I don't really know hot to prove it.

Don't know what tools can I use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L = \{a^n b^n\}$. Let us take some context free language $L'$ and prove that $L' \cap L$ is context free.

First, as $L \cap \{a^* b^*\} = L$ and $\{a^* b^*\}$ is regular, it's enough to consider cases when $L' \subseteq \{a^* b^*\}$.

Now, let us write grammar $G$ for $L'$ in Chomsky normal form. Now we will write another grammar $G_1$ that also generates $L'$.

For every nonterminal $X$ of $G$ we will add nonterminals $X_a$, $X_b$, $X$ to $G_1$ - intuitively $X_a$ will generate the words that can be generated from $X$ and consist only of letter $a$, $X_b$ similarly for $b$.

For each $X$ we add rules $X \to X_a$ and $X \to X_b$.

For each rule $X \to a$ we add rule $X_a \to a$, similarly for $b$. For each rule $X \to \varepsilon$ we add rule $X \to \varepsilon$.

For each rule $X \to YZ$ we add rules $X \to Y Z_b$, $X \to Y_a Z$ (intuitively, when we generate a word using $G$, we will either generate only $a$'s from $Y$, or only $b$'s from $Z$ - otherwise our word will not be in $a^*b^*$). We also add  $X_a \to Y_a Z_a$ and $X_b \to Y_b Z_b$

Now, let us note that each $X_a$ generates a context-free language in single-letter alphabet $\{a\}$, and each $X_b$ generates a context-free language in single-letter alphabet $\{b\}$. Therefore, $X_a$ generates left-regular language, and $X_b$ generates right-regular language. So by adding new non-terminals we can create grammar $G_2$ that still generates $L'$, but in which all rules are of form $X \to Y Z_b$, $X \to Y_a Z$, $X_a \to a Y_a$, $X_b \to Y_b b$, $X_a \to \varepsilon$, $Y_b \to \varepsilon$.

Now let us finally define grammar $G_3$ that generates $L \cap L'$.

It will use $(X)$, $(X_a)$, $(X_b)$, $(X_a Y)$, $(Y Z_b)$, $(X_a Z_b)$, $(X_a Y Z_b)$ as nonterminals (is nonterminal for $G_3$ is one, two or three nonterminals of $G_2$). Intuitively, as we need to support number of $a$ and $b$ equal, we will can generate them in pairs and it will be enough for us to have at most $3$ nonterminals, with them been in the center of the string.

For each rule like $X \to Y Z_b$ of $G_2$ and for non-terminal of form $P_a$ of $G_2$ we add rule $(X) \to (Y Z_b)$, $(P_a X) \to (P_a Y Z_b)$. For each rule $X \to \varepsilon$ we add rule $(X) \to \varepsilon$.

For each rule $X_a \to X'_a$ and for each $U$ of kind $Y$ or $Y Z_b$ we add rule $(X_a U) \to (X'_aU)$. Similarly for rules $X_a \to \varepsilon$ and for $b$.

And now the most important part: for each pair of rules $X_a \to a X'_a$ and $Z_B \to Z'_b b$ and for each $Y$ we add rule $(X_a Y Z_b) \to a(X'_a Y Z'_b)b$. Intuitively, we write symbols only in pairs.

Then, if we had some generating path in $G_2$, we can transform it to generating path in $G_3$: if a non-terminal $X_a$ will produce at least one letter, we can produce it simultaneously with producing $b$ from some other non-terminal.

Comment: I lost you in the first line.. What is L in your first line? in the second, what do you mean by $L\cup \{a^*b^*\}=L$? you mean $L\cap\{a\cup b\}^*=L$?

Comment: The way I know, $\{a^*b^*\}$ is equivalent to the words $a^ib^j$ for some natural (or zero) numbers $i, j$

Comment: Sorry, $L$ is $\{a^n b^n\}$. And I indeed meant $L \cap \{a^*b^*\}$.

Comment: Sorry for late comment, you say for each rule $X \rightarrow YZ$ we add rules $X \rightarrow Y_a Z$ and $X \rightarrow YZ_b$ but what is you got a rule $X \rightarrow X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ for some $n > 2$? and what if it combines with terminals?

Comment: OK if I understand, I will generate all the rules of the form:
  $X_1_a X_2_a....X_(i-1)_a X_i X_(i+1)_b...X_n_b$  for every $1<=i<=n$?

Sorry about the strange format.. don't know hot to fix it

Comment: We assumed $G$ is in Chomsky normal form, so each rule is of form $X \to YZ$, $X \to t$ where $t$ is terminal, or $X \to \varepsilon$.

Comment: Ok I didnt study Chomsky but its not a big difference so I am cool with that issue..another question - the only rule you gave to $X_a$ is $X_a \to a$ so what do you mean $X_a$ generates a context-free language in single-letter alphabet? It can generate only the word $\{a\}$

Comment: It means I didn't proofread enough: there should me two more rules (added now). Sorry about this. Feel free to ask about the next thing where I did mistake:)

Comment: Ok step by step I am getting it.. in the end of the line that start with "For each rule.." did you mean to write $(X)\to(YZ_b)$? and why is it helpfull that $X_a$ and $X_b$ are regular? I understand why they are, dont get where do we use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92299/discussion-between-mihaild-and-shaq).